# VAT Tax (EU from UK) not displaying on shopping basket

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, vat

The VAT Tax breakdown isn't being shown on the shopping basket when a visitor adds a product to it. If they go to checkout, and then back (without doing anything in checkout), it will display the breakdown. Otherwise it just displays a sub total and total (which are exactly the same).

The settings we have configured are:

- Tax calculation method based on: Unit Price
- Tax Calculation Based On: Shipping Address
- Catalog Prices: Excluding Tax
- Delivery Prices: Excluding Tax
- Apply Customer Tax: After Discount
- Apply Discount On Prices: Excluding Tax
- Default Country: UK
- Default State/Post Code: *

Shopping Cart Display Settings

- Prices: Excluding Tax
- Sub Total: Excluding Tax
- Delivery Amount: Incl. and Excl. Tax
- Include Tax in Grand Total: No (Even on yes, this just shows two prices exactly the same, without VAT being added on).

There are several Tax rates set up, one for each applicable country at 20%. The Tax Rule is applied to retail customers and taxable goods; the issue seems to happen when multiple tax rates are selected (if I just select the UK VAT one, prices display as expected, otherwise if I select them all, it only displays ex VAT in everything).

Any ideas? I've followed both magento guides/documentation and other blog posts on doing this, and none of them help resolve the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing the tax rate from a CSV there was a missing column of `default` which can have a `1` inside it to represent which tax rate is the default tax rate.

I was using the CSV from http://www.mcnab.co/blog/e-commerce/magento/magento-vat-setup-for-countries-trading-worldwide/ which was missing several columns compared to the Magento export version. So I had to re-import the tax rates to fix the issue.

The columns missed (following the `Rate` column) were `Zip/Post is Range`, `Range From`, `Range To` and `default` which can all be left blank (except I placed a 1 in the default tax rate I wanted to use, e.g. UK VAT)

Hope that helps anyone else that encounters this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the Tax Origin not being set correctly (it's probably on its default: US). This is different from the Default Country setting, you can find it at `System -> Configuration -> [SALES] Tax -> Origin`.

Let me know if it works! :)

Comment: There isn't a "Origin" option, but there is a "Default Tax Destination Calculation - Default Country" which is set to UK. So no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Argh, excuse me, I translated it from Dutch, thinking it was a different option. Sorry!